# Why does json_query return an empty string in a set_fact?

Tags: json, ansible

I tried to get metrics2 and metrics3 value like below:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
       param:
        - - {metrics1: A, metrics2: B, metrics3: C}
          - {metrics1: D, metrics2: E, metrics3: F}
          - {metrics1: G, metrics2: H, metrics3: I}
        - - {metrics1: J, metrics2: K, metrics3: L}
          - {metrics1: M, metrics2: N, metrics3: O}
          - {metrics1: P, metrics2: Q, metrics3: R}
      parseParam: "{{ param | json_query('[][].[metrics2, metrics3]') }}"

    - debug:
        var: parseParam
```

and the returned value is null:

```json
"parseParam": ""
```

What should I do?

Comment: At a first glance it seems to be more like a typo. `set_fact` belongs to the `task` level. Otherwise you should use the `vars` keyword instead.

Comment: it is on the tasks level, i missplaced it before sorry, i have edited the right one

Comment: The `param` variable isn't available until *after* the `set_fact` task has executed. If you want to reference it in `parseParam`, you'll need a second `set_fact` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to access `param` in the `set_fact` that defines it.

A way around is to declare a variable local to that task, and use it:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    parseParam: "{{ _param | json_query('[][].[metrics2, metrics3]') }}"
    param: "{{ _param }}"
  vars:
    _param:
      - - {metrics1: A, metrics2: B, metrics3: C}
        - {metrics1: D, metrics2: E, metrics3: F}
        - {metrics1: G, metrics2: H, metrics3: I}
      - - {metrics1: J, metrics2: K, metrics3: L}
        - {metrics1: M, metrics2: N, metrics3: O}
        - {metrics1: P, metrics2: Q, metrics3: R}
```

If you don't need the `param` variable outside of the `set_fact` itself, you can even drop its assignation in a fact, of course.